# How to write if statement - If count is the same for each item in list, python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to count the items in my data list.  How would I write a statement that says, “If count is the same for all items”?
Something like:

```
data = ['a', 'a', 'a' ,'b' ,'b' ,'b','c' ,'c' ,'c']

for i in range(len(data)):
    count = data.count(data[i])
    print data[i], count
    ...
    ...
    ...
    if count == all(count)??????
    do something
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do the counting for you, then see if the set of values is just length 1:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(data)

if len(set(counts.values()) == 1:
    # do something
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> data = ['a', 'a', 'a' ,'b' ,'b' ,'b','c' ,'c' ,'c']
>>> counts = Counter(data)
>>> len(set(counts.values()))
1
```

Comment: Looking for something a little different without importing functions